# S3 doesObjectExist API is not recognizing path with equal symbol

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a Apache Spark application which is writing to S3 folder, since the Spark application is partitioning the data while writing to S3 it has adding EQUAL symbol like below.

s3://biops/XXX/YYY/entryDateYear=2018/entryDateMonth=07

I totally understand that S3 does not allow to create bucket_name with "=" , but spark streaming creates partition with field_name followed by "="  and then value.

Please advise on how to access S3 folder with equal sign.

```
// Actual paths in S3 is --> biops/XXX/YYY/royalty_raw_json/entryDateYear=2018/

String bucket = "biops";
String without_equal = "XXX/YYY/royalty_raw_json/";
String with_equal = "XXX/YYY/royalty_raw_json/entryDateYear=2018";
String with_equal_encoding = "XXX/YYY/royalty_raw_json/entryDateYear%3D2018";

AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().
        withCredentials(getCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withRegion("us-east-1")
        .build();
amazonS3.doesObjectExist(bucket, without_equal); // Works
amazonS3.doesObjectExist(bucket, with_equal); // Not works
amazonS3.doesObjectExist(bucket, with_equal_encoding); // Not works 2
```

**UPDATE**
I managed with a work around to list the objects as below to check if a folder is present are not

```
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withPrefix(with_equal);
ObjectListing bucketListing = amazonS3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
if (bucketListing != null && bucketListing.getObjectSummaries() != null && bucketListing.getObjectSummaries().size() > 0)
    System.out.println("Folder present with files");
else
    System.out.println("Folder present with zero files or Folder not present");
```

Comment: thanx,,, save my day

Comment: Thanks man, doesObjectExist works unpredictable